# Vue awesome swiper play video if content is video

Tags: vuejs2, vue-slider-component

I'am using Vuejs2 and vue awesome swiper,
I can add video autoplay in slider but i can't control video play when slide active in video data. can video autoplay just when slider active in video?.

This is my code

```
<swiper :options="swiperOption">
                <swiper-slide v-for="(slider, index) in sliders" :key="index" :data-swiper-autoplay="slider.delay">
                  <img :src="`http://localhost:8000/photos/image/${slider.img}`">
                    <video id="video" autoplay :src= "slider.video"></video>
                </swiper-slide>
              </swiper>
<script>

export default {
data() {
    return {
      private: {
            privateData : 'private'
      },
      swiperOption: {
        notNextTick: true,
          setWrapperSize :true,
        spaceBetween: 30,
        centeredSlides: true,
        autoplay: {
          delay: 500,
          disableOnInteraction: false
        },
        pagination: {
          el: ".swiper-pagination",
          clickable: true
        },
        navigation: {
          nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
          prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev"
        },
        // history: {
        //   replaceState: true
        // }
      }
    };
  },
}

</script>
```

Thanks